# Just wondering if these 2 questions are considered duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This [UIView's frame, bounds, center, origin, when to use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071112/uiviews-frame-bounds-center-origin-when-to-use-what?rq=1)

and this [UIView frame, bounds and center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/uiview-frame-bounds-and-center)

Edit: This one too [Cocoa: What's the difference between the frame and the bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210047/cocoa-whats-the-difference-between-the-frame-and-the-bounds)

Answer (score 1):

Both 1 and 3 have the same content as the 2nd checked answer which is way more complete.

So yes it can be considered as a duplicate, but thy are quite olds questions maybe ask for someone with a gold badge to close them as duplicate.

But idon't think it's worth using 5 closing votes for this.

You can just add a comment on 1 & 3 linking it to the 2nd one. So the 2nd post will bee seen in the 'link' menu.